# Close Parent with Modal Form

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void btnOpenModalWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var modalForm = new modalForm(EventDetails))
        {
            modalForm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
```

Inside the modal window:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Close();
    }
```

I want to close the parent form also when I close the modal window but I'm not sure how to do that from the modal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found exactly what I was looking for, and its so ridiculously simple I'm ashamed to have even asked.

```
Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the `Owner` that you already passed as parameter to `ShowDialog`

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Owner.Close();
}
```

Comment: +1 as I'm sure this'll work but Application.Exit() is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a cleaner way is to do:

```
private void btnOpenModalWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var modalForm = new modalForm(EventDetails))
        {
            if (modalForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Allows you to check the return code if you don't want to exit. Or just close after ShowDialog.